# Code to Select the table whose name is listed in the textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with one textbox. There are several tables in my worksheet. What i want is when i run the userform and enter the table of table in it, on pressing submit, it should find that table whose name is entered in textbox and then select the cell of that table. so far i have written this code as i am a beginner.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

'Unprotect the Worksheet
Sheets("Control Heads").Unprotect Password:="google"

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, tbl As ListObjects, row As ListRow

Set ws1 = Sheets("Control Heads")
Set tbl = ws1.ListObjects("Me.TextBox2.Value")
Set row = tbl.ListRows.Add

End Sub
```

Kindly review the code and tell me where i am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: If you're going set `worksheet`, qualify it with the workbook as well... and do it for all sheets? And what's the point of having code just to select a table?

Comment: Basically after selecting a particular table, i want to add row at the bottom of that table and then place the entry in it.

Comment: You want to qualify the sheet with the workbook like `set ws1=nameOfBookHere.Sheets("Control Heads")`. Please look up how to use `set`. Consider storing the value of `Me.TextBox2` to a variable and use that instead?

Comment: i want the textbox2 value or text to be used to trace the table in worksheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

'Unprotect the Worksheet
Sheets("Control Heads").Unprotect Password:="google"

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, row As ListRow 
'tbl should be dim as ListObject, not ListObjects

Set ws1 = Sheets("Control Heads")
Set tbl = ws1.ListObjects(Me.TextBox2.Value) '<-- no quotation mark
Set row = tbl.ListRows.Add

End Sub
```

Comment: try use `me.textbox2.text`

Comment: ah ... `Dim tbl as ListObject` ... no 's' behind